VS CODE connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9000
I keep getting an error message:
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9000

when trying to debug a python script in VS Code.
Two buttons at bottom, [Open 'launch.json'] and [Cancel]
This is the launch.json script:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
                    "remoteRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
                }
            ],
            "osx": {
                "filePath": "${file}"
            },
            "windows": {
                "filePath": "${file}"
            },
            "port": 9000,
            "host": "localhost"
        }
    ]
}

The python code is for Fusion360
Don't know what to do to get it to work.
Shut down all apps and rebooted the computer.
No change.
It worked two days ago, but not yesterday or today.
